# EXT JS 6.0.2 Donut Chart Crashes Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, extjs

Chrome browser crashes ("Aw Snap!") randomly when rendering Ext JS Donut Charts.

I initially thought this was a data issue. But, I was able to reproduce it even on Ext JS Kitchen sink (http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#pie-donut)

To reproduce this just check and un-check the boxes on Legend below the donut chart. which will cause the chart to re-render and eventually crash (it sometimes takes me 20,30+ clicks to reproduce this).

This issue is limited to Chrome Browser only.

I've found few threads describing the same issue

[Link1](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?311910-Google-Chrome-crashes-when-drawing-Pie-chart)

[Link2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/fHB4qJzCBMQ)

But, No solution yet. 
I need help finding a workaround or solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is known Chrome issue - should be fixed in Chrome 55

Comment: @pagep Can you please point me to the issue tracker? is there a way for me to verify this fix on Chrome 55? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known Chrome issue. Should be fixed with [Chrome 55](https://googlechromereleases.blogspot.cz/2016/12/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_9.html) which was released couple of days ago.

You can see the Chromium ticket here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=666046

Testing: I have app which uses Ext 6.2 charts interactions a lot. It used to crash in couple of seconds - with version 55 so far no crash! :)

Comment: updated to latest version of chrome. It appears to be working fine now. I'll do some testing and mark this as answer. Thanks

Comment: @JasonDias I updated Chrome couple of hours ago - testing on my apps, so far looks very promising - in one of my app it used to crash almost instantly now it runs smoothly :)